# Python-Sybase on Windows 7 Python 2.7 32bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, sybase

I'm trying to build python-sybase on windows with very limited success.

I have followed the instructions on the [sybase module homepage](http://python-sybase.sourceforge.net/install.html) but still experience errors.  I have tried the following approaches:

1. Download and unzip python-sybase (python-sybase-0.40pre2)

**Visual Studio (2013)**

1. Open Visual Studio Command Prompt Shell
2. Override path in VS90COMNTOOLS to prevent Visual Studio version errors (SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS120COMNTOOLS%​)
3. Run python setup.py install.

Both methods appear to work and generate identical results.  The only warning I see is the 'Normalizing' warning from setuptools.py:

```
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-15.2-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dist.py:282: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.40pre2' to '0.40rc2'
```

The error message I see when trying to run:

```
import Sybase
```

is:

```
import Sybase
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-3cf190f37cd0>", line 1, in <module>
    import Sybase

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Sybase.py", line 317, in <module>

InternalError
```

The section in Sybase.py (line 317) where the code fails is:

```
# Setup global library context
status, _ctx = cs_ctx_alloc()
if status != CS_SUCCEED:
    raise InternalError('cs_ctx_alloc failed')
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Infocenter.sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ocs_12.5.1.comlib/html/comlib/X31916.htm)

Basically the error is due to incorrect/missing configuration information in the \locales\locales.dat file for the target OS as per link above:

*'The most common reason for a cs_ctx_alloc failure is a misconfigured system environment. cs_ctx_alloc must read the locales file that specifies the default localization values for the allocated context. If CS-Library cannot find the locales file or if the locales file is misconfigured, cs_ctx_alloc fails.'*

I missed the sybinit.err file which would of been very useful and saved a lot of time!

*'The context allocation routine failed when it tried to load localization files!!
One or more following problems may caused the failure

Your sybase home directory is C:\Program Files\Sybase. Check the environment variable SYBASE if it is not the one you want!
Using locale name "en_GB" defined in environment variable LANG
Locale name "en_GB" doesn't exist in your C:\Program Files\Sybase\locales\locales.dat file'*

**Changing the LANG environment variable to 'enu' or editing the .dat file corrected this issue.**